# iNotify single read

Tags: c++, inotify

How do you get iNotify to only read a file once?

I have the following code:

```
int settingsCheck(int &length, int &i, char * buffer, int &fd, string setRead[])
{
    int f_change = 0;

    struct pollfd pfd = { fd, POLLIN, 0 };
    /* Poll with a timeout of 100ms */
    int ret = poll(&pfd, 1, 100);
    /* Check to see the result of the poll */
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Poll failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    else if (ret == 0) {
        /* Timeout with no events -> move on */
    }
    else {
        /* Process the new event */
        struct inotify_event event;
        length = read(fd, buffer, BUF_LEN);
        printf("read\n");

        while (i < length)
        {
            struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *) &buffer[i];
            if (event->len)
            {
                if (event->mask & IN_MODIFY)
                {
                    printf("The file %s was modified.\n", event->name);
                    readSettings(setRead);
                    //f_change = 1;
                }
            }
            i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
        }
        //readSettings(setRead);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This uses poll to make sure the function does not block with read. When a file is modified, "read\n" is printed twice and the file is read twice (my guess is the first read is for clearing of the file and the second for writing to it). I made sure that my php code that accesses the file only does one "fprintf" statement, thus only a single write, yet the iNotify checking for modify reads twice, perhaps because of the clear and then write?

Is there a way to work around this??

Comment: What event type do you get for each of reads?

Comment: what are the flags you have registered in inotify_add_watch() ?